# Question about 'ascending to the throne' for other titles

Tags: phrase-requests

When talking about the heir to a king, when he/she comes into power, we can say he ascended to the throne. Is there an equivalent phrase for usage concerning other noble titles like duke, count, baron, earl etc.?

Answer (score 2):

You [*accede*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&btnG=Search&q=define+accede) to a position of nobility.

[Accession](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=accede&t=crmtb01) is used to indicate the inheritance of a title or position of some authority.  It implies agreement to undertake the responsibities of office, the word is also used to describe the act of agreeing to another's requirements.

The word can also be used for a monarch.  Accession to the throne is as commonly used as ascent to the throne.

Comment: Thank you. So If we were talking about the heir of a Duke, when his father died should we say "He acceded to the position." or "He acceded." or "He acceded to the dukedom." ? I'm not sure why but all of these options sound clunky to me. I suppose I'm not sure what the object of accede should be in specific instance of certain titles.

Comment: "Acceded" alone could possibly be ambiguous but "Acceded to the title / position / dukedom" would all be acceptable.